# How to set C++ compiler flags in Visual Studio(2015

Tags: c++

I want to set some compiler flags in visual studio 2015 for a C++ program but I can't see how.  Using another IDE (CodeBlocks) I can select the following with a tick box:

Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard

Also, I can create my own new flag (with name, Compiler flags and linker flags set )

How can I modify and create these two flags on VS2015 ?

I've checked https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 but no luck.

**here is a picture of codeblocks ide and compiler settings 
[image]

**edit here is VS2015 configuration settings 
[image]

Comment: You can set most of these via the IDE, however one or two are missing these can be put into the "other option" (I think it's called) box:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx  MS does not provide flags for C++11, C++14 etc  The compilers supported language standard is part of its documentation.

Answer (score 23):

You can add options by selecting the Project properties -> Config Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line, and then add them to the bottom section "Additional Options".

Answer (score -1):

Qouted from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3600tzxa.aspx) link.

> You can set compiler options for each project in its **Property Pages** dialog box. In the left pane, select **Configuration Properties, C/C++** and then choose the compiler option category.

**Update:**
To add language specification use [/std](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490614.aspx) flag. Append it at the end of existing flags in **Command Line** option page.

Comment: I see that but I don't have compiler option under configuration properties.

Comment: @Aindriu are you really sure you selected the project, and not a file? Also, there is no way to change the c++ standard in visual studio 2015, you'll have to use 2017

Comment: There is a **Command Line** option page under **Configuration Properties > C/C++**. You can specify any compiler option. To specify C++ language standard you can use [**/std**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490614.aspx) flag.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't get it to work yet.  I think I need to add -mwindows and -std=c++11 flags but no changes - program is still running like before

Comment: @Aindriu Those are GCC options. Visual Studio does not use GCC.

Comment: @Aindriu different compilers use different command-line options; for `-std=c++11` see `/std:c++14` from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490614.aspx  `-mwindows` is not required with MSVC.