# If statement doesn't detect empty string

Tags: c, string, validation, if-statement

I have a C app that takes user input from stdin. I have a validation function that is supposed to detect when a user presses `ENTER` without writing anything into the console. I've tried `if (strSurveyDate[0] == "")` and `if (strcmp(strSurveyDate[0], "") == 0)`, but those don't work. The first one simply doesn't execute (the condition isn't satisfied, apparently), and the second one gives an `access violation reading location 0x00000000` error. I have a `Trim()` function that strips out leading and trailing whitespace before sending the input to the function for validation, so I can't simply look for `\n`, `\r`, and so on. I've stepped through the code, and `""` is what is being sent to the function.

I'm not sure if I need to include more code, but I will. This is the entire validation function:

```
int ValidateSurveyDate(char strSurveyDate[])
{
    // declare variables
    int intTrue = 1;
    int intFalse = 0;

    // validate that input was entered
    if (strcmp(strSurveyDate[0], "") == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Please enter a survey date.\n");
        return intFalse;
    }
    else { return intTrue; }
}
```

And this is the code where I get the user input and send it to the validation function:

```
printf("Please enter the date of the survey.\n");
fgets(strSurveyDate, sizeof(strSurveyDate), stdin);
Trim(strSurveyDate);

// validate date of survey
if (ValidateSurveyDate(strSurveyDate) == 1)
```

Let me know if I need to include anything else, and I'll be happy to include it. Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

---

Here's the `Trim()` function, as requested:

```
void Trim(char strSource[])
{

    int intIndex = 0;
    int intFirstNonWhitespaceIndex = -1;
    int intLastNonWhitespaceIndex = 0;
    int intSourceIndex = 0;
    int intDestinationIndex = 0;

    // Default first non-whitespace character index to end of string in case string is all whitespace
    intFirstNonWhitespaceIndex = StringLength(strSource);

    // Find first non-whitespace character
    while (strSource[intIndex] != 0)
    {
        // Non-whitespace character?
        if (IsWhiteSpace(strSource[intIndex]) == 0)
        {
            // Yes, save the index
            intFirstNonWhitespaceIndex = intIndex;

            // Stop searching!
            break;
        }

        // Next character
        intIndex += 1;
    }

    // Find the last non-whitespace character
    while (strSource[intIndex] != 0)
    {
        // Non-whitespace character?
        if (IsWhiteSpace(strSource[intIndex]) == 0)
        {
            // Yes, save the index
            intLastNonWhitespaceIndex = intIndex;
        }

        // Next character
        intIndex += 1;
    }

    // Any non-whitepsace characters?
    if (intFirstNonWhitespaceIndex >= 0)
    {
        // Yes, copy everything in between
        for (intSourceIndex = intFirstNonWhitespaceIndex; intSourceIndex <= intLastNonWhitespaceIndex; intSourceIndex += 1)
        {
            // Copy next character
            strSource[intDestinationIndex] = strSource[intSourceIndex];

            intDestinationIndex += 1;
        }
    }

    // Terminate 
    strSource[intDestinationIndex] = 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `Trim()` do?

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`. There should be a warning about `strcmp(strSurveyDate[0], "")`.

Comment: `strSurveyDate[0]` is not a string but a `char`.

Comment: `strcmp(strSurveyDate[0], "")` `strSurveyDate[0]` is a `char`, not a `char*` which is what `strcmp` expects. Do you not get a warning for that?

Comment: @Barmar, I edited the post to include the ```Trim()``` function.

Comment: @Siguza, thanks! How do I do that in Visual Studio?

Comment: Try to fix your warnings before running your code (or posting here).  The compiler would have told you about the bad call to `strcmp`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, no, there are no warnings for that.

Comment: @TomKarzes, there aren't any warnings in my code.

Comment: Did you remember to include `<string.h>`?  If you did, you should have gotten a warning about trying to make a pointer from an integer type.  Make sure you enable warnings.  If you didn't include `<string.h>`, you should have gotten a warning about an implicit declaration for `strcmp`.

Comment: @TomKarzes, yes, and there's still no warning. Where am I trying to make a pointer from an integer type? ```strSurveyDate[0]``` is a char.

Comment: A `char` is an integer type, as are `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, etc.  And it's not a pointer.

Comment: I get the appropriate warning here: https://godbolt.org/z/4aEvMKPGa `passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is what strSurveyDate[0] is a char not a string to compare to.

Try this:

```
int ValidateSurveyDate(char *strSurveyDate){
  // declare variables
  int intTrue = 1;
  int intFalse = 0;

  // validate that input was entered
  if (!strcmp(strSurveyDate, "")){
      printf("ERROR: Please enter a survey date.\n");
      return intFalse;
  }else{
      return intTrue;
  }
}
```

As describes Siguza, always compile with -Wall , this is a common warning.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Also, I'm using Visual Studio to write my program. How do I compile with -Wall?

Comment: @Ethan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908940/how-to-set-c-compiler-flags-in-visual-studio2015