# use of undeclared identifier 'sample'

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a wrapper function for selecting `n` elements randomly from a `vector<int>` object named `target`. Here is my `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

vector<int> select_from(vector<int> target, int n) {
    vector<int> result;
    sample(target.begin(), 
           target.end(), 
           back_inserter(result), 
           n, 
           mt19937(random_device()()));
    return result;
};

int main() {

}
```

where the `stdafx.h` is as followed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
```

But when I tried to run the code it gives me the following error message:
`error: use of undeclared identifier 'sample'; did you mean '__sample'?`. But when I right-click the `sample` function in my code and click `Go to Definition`, it directs me to the right function definition in `<algorithm>`, so why is it an undeclared identifier?

I am using VisualStudio Code for Mac version 1.80.0, the c++ version I am using is `c++20`. Please shed some light on what I am doing wrong. I've been stuck with this for a day now (sob

I've tried to change `sample(...)` to `std::sample(...)`, but then it gives me the error message of `error: no member named 'sample' in namespace 'std'`

I've also tried to switch compilers: `/usr/bin/g++`, `/usr/bin/clang`, `/usr/bin/gcc`, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++20` (or at least >= `-std=c++14`)? It seems that `libstdc++` gates `std::sample` on C++14 [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/14d8a5ae472ca5743016f37da2dd4770d83dea21/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L5743-L5869)

Comment: works: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20a924bcf25a1f60

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Could you explain a bit more on how to use the command `-std=c++20`? I am new to c++ and VS code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::sample` is a C++17 option. Are you compiling with the option /std:c++17 (MSVC) or -std=c++17 (GCC, clang)? Adding that flag may solve your problem.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on how to use the command `-std=c++17`? I am new to c++ and VS code

Comment: @RayHCW `-std=c++17` is a compiler flag you add to GCC or Clang when compiling C++ code. `/std:c++17` would be the equivalent for MSVC (windows).

Comment: @RayHCW In order to use the flag, you append it to the compile command that you are using. For clang, that might be `clang++ main.cpp -std=c++17`

Comment: @RayHCW if you are using Microsoft visual studio code to compile, I'm linking the following stack overflow article which describes how to set this flag in the IDE (integrated development environment, which is what visual studio is): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908940/how-to-set-c-compiler-flags-in-visual-studio2015